# Hide skipped ansible tasks without using display_skipped_hosts

Tags: ansible

I have an ansible role with this:

```yaml
---
- import_tasks: foo.yml
  when: ShouldRunFoo
```

If `ShouldRunFoo == false` then the file is skipped, but the console shows its tasks (as "skipped").

I could use the `display_skipped_hosts = no` [config option](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html#display-skipped-hosts), but that hides *everything* skipped in a playbook, not just `foo.yml`.

Is there a way to do this? I want to see skipped tasks, just not those from `foo.yml` (if it is skipped).

Answer (score 2):

I struggled with that sometime ago and using different sources I found one approach that is not pretty clean but do the trick. (I am assuming you know about the `display_skipped_hosts=no` and you still want to print some of the skipped ones)

You can do a loop using Jinja expression to delete the messages from the debug output (The titles of the task will always be shown):

```yaml
---
- hosts: all
  tasks:
    - name: task to skip and display
      debug:
        msg: "HELLO WORLD"
      when: "'SOMETHING' in group_names"
    - name: task to skip and  not display
      debug:
        msg: "HELLO WORLD"
      loop: "{% if 'SOMETHING' in group_names%} {{debug_list}}{% else %}[]{% endif %}"
```

Comment: Thanks for this, but how to use this when importing tasks? Loops don't work with imports. And what are all those variables, there's no context, e.g. `debug_list`?

Answer (score 1):

If *in a specific use case*, you can use either `import_tasks` or `include_tasks`, then do this:

`$ cat playbook.yml`:

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - name: subtasks will be printed
      import_tasks: tasks.yml
      when: false
    - name: subtasks will not be printed
      include_tasks: tasks.yml            # <----------
      when: false
```

`$ cat tasks.yml`:

```yaml
---
- debug: msg=1
- debug: msg=2
- debug: msg=3
```

`$ ansible-playbook playbook.yml`:

```
PLAY [localhost] **************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] ********************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [debug] ******************************************************************
skipping: [localhost]

TASK [debug] ******************************************************************
skipping: [localhost]

TASK [debug] ******************************************************************
skipping: [localhost]

TASK [subtasks will not be printed] *******************************************
skipping: [localhost]

PLAY RECAP ********************************************************************
localhost : ok=1 changed=0 unreachable=0 failed=0 skipped=4 rescued=0 ignored=0
```

I imagine this will not always be applicable, so it's not a perfect solution.